# Can't make sense of the output of this C snippet

Tags: c, printf

In the following code, is the behaviour undefined ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf(7+"%c","sundaram");  
}
```

Its printing "aram". Can't understand how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the behavior is **undefined** because the expression `7+"%c"` does not point to an element within the array or one past the end of the array.  See the online C language standard, draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 6.5.6 ¶ 8 for details.

By coincidence your strings are laid out in memory like so (using an imaginary starting address):

```
Address         0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
-------         ----------------------
0x00008000      '%'   'c'   0     's'
0x00008004      'u'   'n'   'd'   'a'
0x00008008      'r'   'a'   'm'   0
```

"%c" starts at 0x00008000 and "sundaram" starts at 0x000080003.

When you call

```
printf(7+"%c", "sundaram");
```

the array expression "%c" is converted from type `char [3]` to `char *`, and its value is the address of the first element in the array, or 0x00008000.  The expression `7+"%c"` thus evaluates to 7+0x00008000, or 0x00008007.  The string that starts at 0x00008007 is "aram".

Since "aram" contains no conversion specifiers, the second argument ("sundaram", which evaluates to 0x00008003) is evaluated but otherwise ignored (§ 7.19.6.1, ¶ 2).

Since the behavior is undefined, *any* result is possible; this particular result isn't guaranteed to happen with a different compiler, or with different compiler settings.

Answer (score 6):

This is undefined behavior.

A string literal in C is a pointer to a a block of pre-initialized memory.
By coincidence, your two string literals occupy adjacent blocks of memory.
When you add `7` to the pointer to the first literal, you end up pointing into the middle of the next literal.

Your program's data is arranged in memory like this:

```
       %c\0sundaram\0
       |       |
"%c" --^       |
7 + "%c" ------^
```

Therefore, you end up calling `printf` with two pointers into the same string `("adam", "sundadam")` and no format specifiers.

Comment: Thanks. But, why is it not considering "%c" as a format specifier ? if we replace 7 with 0, it gives a warning and the output shows nothing, when it should have shown "%c"

Comment: Because when it looks at sequential characters in memory, starting 7 past where the '%c' is, it never sees the '%c'.

Comment: @Duad: You're passing it a pointer to `"adam"`, not to `"%c"`.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is undefined. It just so happens that the data is laid out in memory like this: "%c\0sundaram\0", and you get the part of "sundaram" string as a format string argument (in absence of format specifiers in a format string remaining printf arguments are ignored).

Comment: Thanks. You said "in absence of format specifiers....." But there IS a format specifier. No ?

Comment: There is no format specifier as far as printf is concerned - the effect of undefined behavior in your case is passing "aram" to printf as a format string, which has no format specifiers.